# Woocommerce 'Add to Cart' button missing after progmatically adding product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a plugin which adds a custom product to Woocommerce programatically successfully. The problem is that when a user navigates to the product page for the first time there is no "Add to Cart" button visible. I can solve this manually by editing the product and then saving it, without touching anything else. I have no idea why this works, and I'd like to solve it programatically.

To get from:
[image]

1. I click "edit"
2. I click "update"
3. Then I see:

[image]

How do I make the "Add to Cart" button visible programatically?

Fired on 'init':

```
public function createRaffleProduct(){
    global $CRG_productName;
    global $CRG_regularPrice;
    $post = array(
        'post_author' => $user_id,
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => "publish",
        'post_title' => $CRG_productName,
        'post_parent' => '',
        'post_type' => "product",
    );
    //Create post:
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post, $wp_error );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_visibility', 'visible' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'total_sales', '0');
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_downloadable', 'no');
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_virtual', 'yes');
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', $CRG_regularPrice);
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price', "1" );
}
```

Comment: At first glance, I think you might be missing  `_price` meta key. Take a close look at what happens on `save_post` and make sure you are using all the same meta.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it, but this isn't a question about Codeception, so I removed the tag and explanation why you mentioned it.

Comment: Helgathevicking, that worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a product programatically, you must ensure that you are using all the same meta as WooCommerce generates on `save_post`.

From your code, you are missing the `_price` meta key. Without a `_price` then the product is not `purchasable` and the add to cart button would not appear.